# How to retrieve data with php phalcon calendar

Tags: php, database, calendar, phalcon

I'm using phalcon-2.1.0. I just create a calendar for my blog archive. i want to retrieve data from database which is matched with the date. my code retrieve only one post and that is my last post in db. I'm not understanding how to query loop through to check the date related data. I need to retrieve that posts which is related with the date users clicked.

[controller]

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $bloger = Blogs::find();
    $postedDays = [];
    foreach ($bloger as $blog) {
       $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($blog->datetime));

       if (!in_array($date, $postedDays)) {
           $postedDays[] = $date;
       }
    }
    $this->view->setvar('dates', $postedDays);        
}

public function archivesAction($date)
{
    $archs = Blogs::find(["datetime LIKE :key:","bind"=>["key"=>'%'.$date.'%']]);        
    $this->view->setvar('dates', $archs);
    $this->view->pick('blog/archive');
}
```

[Calendar in blog page]

```
    <?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");
if(!isset($_REQUEST['month'])){$month = date("m");}else{$month = $_REQUEST['month'];}
if(!isset($_REQUEST['year'])){$year = date("Y");}else{$year = $_REQUEST['year'];}
if(!isset($_REQUEST['day'])){$day = date('d');}else{$day = $_REQUEST['day'];}   
$timestamp = mktime (0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
$monthName = date("F", $timestamp);
$prev_year = $year;
$next_year = $year;
$prev_month = $month-1;
$next_month = $month+1;
if($prev_month == 0 ){$prev_month = 12;$prev_year = $year - 1;}
if($next_month == 13 ){$next_month = 1;$next_year = $year + 1;}
$prev_month = str_pad($prev_month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$next_month = str_pad($next_month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
?>

<div class="table">
<div class="tr caption">
<div class="th L"><a href="blog?month=<?php echo($prev_month.'&amp;year='.$prev_year);?>">&lsaquo;</a></div>
<div class="th monyer"><?php echo($monthName.'-'.$year); ?></div>
<div class='th R'><a href="blog?month=<?php echo($next_month); ?>&amp;year=<?php echo($next_year);?>">&rsaquo;</a></div>
</div>

<div class='thead'>
<div class="td">S</div>
<div class="td">M</div>
<div class="td">T</div>
<div class="td">W</div>
<div class="td">T</div>
<div class="td">F</div>
<div class="td">S</div>
</div>

<?php
$monthstart = date("w", $timestamp);
$lastday = date("d", mktime (0, 0, 0, $month + 1, 0, $year));
$startdate = -$monthstart;
//Figure out how many rows we need.
$numrows = ceil (((date("t",mktime (0, 0, 0, $month + 1, 0, $year))
+ $monthstart) / 7));
//Let's make an appropriate number of rows...
for ($k = 1; $k <= $numrows; $k++){
?><div class="tr days"><?php
//Use 7 columns (for 7 days)...
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
$startdate++;
$startdate = str_pad($startdate, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); //Make dates leading zero
if ($startdate <= 0){
//If we have a blank day in the calendar.
?>

<div class="td L"><?php echo("&nbsp;");?></div>
<?php }elseif($startdate > $lastday){echo('<div class="td R">&nbsp;</div>');}else {
if ($startdate == date("d") && $month == date("m") && $year == date("Y")){?>
<div class="td today"><?php echo($startdate); ?></div><?php
} else { ?>
<?php if(in_array($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$startdate, $dates)) { ?>
<div class="td days"><a href="blog/archives/<?php echo($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$startdate); ?>"><?php echo($startdate); ?></a></div>
<?php }else{ ?><div class="td days"><?php echo($startdate); ?></div><?php }?>   
<?php } } } ?></div><?php } ?>
</div>
```

[View - archive.volt]

```
{% for archs in dates %}
<a href="blog/showfull/<?php echo($archs->id); ?>">
    <dl class="archL">
        <dt><b>{{archs.btitle}}</b><br/><em>{{archs.datetime}}</em></dt>
        <dd>{{archs.bintro}}</dd>
    </dl>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ohh, that code is terrible to read. Consider using indents next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `archivesAction` takes a parameter `$date` which you aren't using.

You are basically querying all your blogs and looping through them. While looping you assign values to `$times`, `$dater` and `$timer`. After your `foreach` ends, these values will have the date of your last blog record.

```
$get = Blogs::find();

foreach($get as $d)
{
    $times = explode(' ', $d->datetime);
    $dater = $times[0];
    $timer = $times[1];
}

$archs = Blogs::find(["datetime LIKE :key:","bind"=>["key"=>'%'.$dater.'%']]);
```

What you should do instead is take the date from the parameter of your action `archivesAction($date)`. Replace the above lines of code with this single line instead:

```
// changed variable $dater to $date
$archs = Blogs::find(["datetime LIKE :key:", "bind" => ["key"=> '%' . $date . '%']]);
```

---

UPDATE

To have your months always output with 2 characters you can do this:

```
<?php prev_month = str_pad($prev_month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>
<a href="blog?month=<?php echo($prev_month.'&amp;year='.$prev_year);?>">&lsaquo;</a>
```

Check [str_pad documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) for more information on this.

---

UPDATE 2

To highlight only your calendar days which have posts in the database, you can do something like this:

[controller]

```
$blogs = Blogs::find();
$uniqueDays = [];

foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
   $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($blog->datetime));

   if (!in_array($date, $uniqueDays)) {
       $uniqueDays[] = $date;
   }
}

$this->view->setVar('databaseDates', $uniqueDays');
```

[view]

```
<?php
if (in_array($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$startdate, $databaseDates) {
   // date is found in the database
   // highlight date
}
```

Comment: i changed dater to date & its working perfectly. but have a small problem that is my date format leading zero in db like 21-07-2016 and my url date format is like 21-7-2016 so that data not rendering. how to make my calendars date leading zero? plz

Comment: url of my calender to go: $next_month or $prev_month <a href="blog?month=<?php echo($prev_month.'&amp;year='.$prev_year);?>">&lsaquo;</a>

Comment: Plz! suggest me how could i highlight post related days? because of all of my calendars day have not data.

Comment: You put that code where you want to check if the date matches any date in your database. So probably somewhere in `<div class="td days">...</div>`. You really should be able to figure this out by yourself.

Comment: I just try like : <div class="td days">
<?php if (in_array($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$startdate, $postedDays)) {?>
 <a href="blog/archives/<?php echo($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$startdate); ?>"><?php echo($startdate); ?></a><?php } ?> 
</div> in my calendar. but it shows error: undefined variable $uniqueDays. Can you please figure it for me?

Comment: In your controller you set "dates" in your view you use "postedDays"

Comment: Timuthy! Muuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuah! A Great Kiss 4 You. Really Bro You r Great. Thank you so much! Its Now Working Perfectly. Any way please check my updated code and please confirm me its ok! thanx Again.